# Gemfire throws 502 Gateway error on starting a locator

Tags: apache, gemfire, geode, gfsh

I had Apache Geode cluster running and I was connected to it using gfsh client. In order to test something, I stopped the Cache Server using, "stop server --name=xxxxserver" command. The Cache server stopped successfully.

Further, I stopped the locator using the "stop locator --name=xxxxlocator" command. The locator stopped successfully. However, my gfsh client connection was also disconnected.

Now, I am trying to reconnect my gfsh client to the locator, but it always gives me a 502 bad gateway error. I have tried accessing the pulse url, I get the same error:

> "502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request."

What I am missing and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

If you stopped your locator, it's expected for `gfsh` and `PULSE` to be disconnected as there's no [JMX Manager](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/11/managing/management/jmx_manager_operations.html) they can talk to. You should start your locator again and re-connect, then everything should be fine.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Right. But, the problem is I am unable to start the locator due to the error I have mentioned. I created another cache instance to verify, but don't see this problem. Stopped/started locator with no issues and able to access the pulse as well.

Comment: How are you trying to restart the locator? From your shell prompt you should be able to issue `gfsh start locator --name=...`